# Changing sharing settings when uploading with Google Picker?

Tags: google-drive-api, file-permissions, google-picker

I am trying to change sharing permissions when uploading files to google with Google Picker. Is that even possible, or do I need to write own methods for changing the permissions after uploading?

Uploading normally with google picker works, but I would want to make the uploaded files 'public'. Now they are 'private' on default.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think there is a way you can change the permissions directly. If you get the file Id, you can just retrieve the file using the Id and change the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems that there is no way to change the permissions straight. Thanks for the comment. Have to do this some other way.